# Fundamental forms and coordinate patch

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

If the following is given: $I_p, II_p$ are the first and the second fundamental forms and maps from $\mathbb R^2 \Rightarrow \mathbb R$ : $I_p = \begin{pmatrix} u^2+1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  $ ; $II_p = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & u \end{pmatrix}  $.

Does there exist a coordinate patch with fundamental forms $I_p$ and $II_p$?

Comment: Have you looked at the Fundamental Theorem of Surface Theory? The Mainardi-Codazzi and Gauss equations are (locally) sufficient to get existence of a surface in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! No, I didn't have this in mind. But I found some information about the Gauss-Codazzi equations. Is it correct that I only have to check that $I_p - II_p = I_p*II_p - II_p*I_p$ ?

Comment: That doesn't look right at all. I don't know what text you're using, but I'll refer you to pp. 59-60 and p. 63 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). Perhaps formula ($*$) on p. 60 will be relevant. You might not need the full strength of this theorem. Maybe two ways of computing the Gaussian curvature will suffice.

Comment: Ahhh all right! Thanks a lot for the link. So I only have to check if the Gaussian curvature of formula (*) is the same as the "traditional" one, calculated using the fundamental forms.

Comment: Since the Gaussian curvatures are not the same ==> there isn't a coordinate patch with the indicated fundamental forms.